# FoneMonkey able to input text to a UITextView?

Tags: iphone, ios4, automated-tests

So far found ways to get FoneMonkey to behave for most of what I'm scripting, however, when trying to enter text into a UITextView, it does not capture it during recording. If I manually add a InputText command for the UITextView, it does not actually input the text.

I'm using the latest version (5.0b).

Unless I missed them, there are no specific examples in the doc showing a command for entering text in a UITextView (there are for UITextField, and that does work for me).

Answer (score 0):

You can input text with the built-in `FMCommandInputText` command, like so:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];

[array addObject:[FMCommandEvent command:FMCommandTouch className:UITextView
                                    monkeyID:TEXTVIEW_MONKEYID args:nil]];

[array addObject:[FMCommandEvent command:FMCommandInputText className:UITextView
                                monkeyID:TEXTVIEW_MONKEYID 
                                    args:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:yourText, nil]]];

result = [FoneMonkeyAPI playCommands:array];
```

Does this work?

Comment: No, did not.  I now also tried to borrow the FoneMonkey generated JavaScript; ran it using Instruments.  There also, the UIText view  ignored the attempt to set a value.  I was desperate to get some text in there one way or another, so what I did was use the JavaScript code from UIAutomation to drive the virtual keyboard to input the text.  That JavaScript approach worked, but it is painfully slow to watch it type in each character.   Tomorrow I'm going to try the suggest approach again, but in an small isolated test program, rather than in my own app.  Will update you on the results.

Comment: Created a standalone app with only one control, a UITextView.  Tried the approach suggested above.  It did not work.  Submitting to FoneMonkey help forum.